# Cannot Connect to third Party GraphQL API in Gatsby using the gatsby-source-graphql package

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-source-apiserver

I tried making graphQL request resources with the following credentials and I got these errors below.

Here are some of the details of the GraphQL info below.

The GraphQL Endpoint is set up:

https://kaleidoscope-graph-ql.herokuapp.com/graphql

Required header "

X-AUTH-HEADER ="7ed06945712f04eecb3f1bcfbf4baee0cf55870b"

I don't know how to set it up in such a way that it returns a 200 ok

```
  {
     resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
     options: {
       typeName: "KL",
       fieldName: "KL",
       url: "https://kaleidoscope-graph-ql.herokuapp.com/graphql",
        // HTTP headers
       headers: {
          // Learn about environment variables: https://gatsby.dev/env-vars
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "X-AUTH-TOKEN": `7ed06945712f04eecb3f1bcfbf4baee0cf55870b`,
       },

      }
    },
```

I am supposed to get a 200 OK and be able to query the data of my company API using the GraphiQL interface. company

My question is that, how can I customize the headers in such a way that it accepts X-AUTH-TOKEN instead of the authorization provided by the gatsby-source-graphql plugin.

```
"gatsby-source-graphql" threw an error while running the source nodes lifecycle:

Response not successful: Received status code 400



  ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400

  - index.ts:114 Object.exports.throwServerError
    [raganortho]/[apollo-link-http-common]/src/index.ts:114:17

  - index.ts:145 
    [raganortho]/[apollo-link-http-common]/src/index.ts:145:11

  - task_queues.js:95 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5
```

**Reproduction Link.**

https://github.com/udemezue01/KL-Issues

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. clone project
2. cd KL-issues
3. npm install.
4. gatsby develop

**Expected Result**

I expected to get a 200 OK response